# Remote desktop connection low virtual memory after restart

Tags: memory, remote-desktop, windows-11, pagefile

I am trying to connect to my orange pi 5 running Armbian 23.02.2 Jammy using remote desktop connection from my laptop, which is running Windows 11. The first attempt was a failure, I got this low virtual memory error:

[image: Low virtual memory]

Then I increased my page file size to 10000 MB, restarted my laptop, and it worked, I could connect to my orange pi.

but then I shut down my laptop, went away for several hours, came back, turned my laptop back on, and tried to connect with rdp again, i got the same low virtual memory error again and failed to connect.

I tried to further increase my page file,

[image: Pagefile size]

and restarted my laptop, to no avail. Still getting the low virtual memory error, and unable to RDP to my orange pi.

How did it work the first time I increased the page file size? but then not anymore?

My memory usage isn't even that high:

[image: Memory usage]

Comment: Not a real answer to your question, but I'd recommend RealVNC

Comment: What does the event viewer say? Please use the System Managed Size of the pagefile, it will only get larger when necessary. Problem may be similar to https://serverfault.com/questions/85501/windows-remote-desktop-rdp-mstsc-fails-with-error-code-5 Check if the drive and RAM are still good

Comment: Have you tried using a different user?

Comment: Hi @MarkusMeyer, to improve the image inlining further by adding an image hover tag and also making the image clickable to expand it, please see my edit. Thanks :-) Also, please flag this comment as no longer needed, once you've read it.

Comment: There is no obvious reason for the problem. I second the advice to search for errors in the Event Viewer, and also in the disk SMART data and `chkdsk`. Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I'm confused. While RDP servers that are not Windows certainly do exist, they are not widely used. Are you sure Remote Desktop Connection is the program you should be using? It is not commonly used for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also note how the error message text is very generic and not helpful. You have an error code (5), that’s the only information you should research.

Comment: Thank you making the images inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out that if I just use ipv4 address instead of the shared name, or fqdn, or even ipv6, everything works just fine:

[image]

[image]

I think the problem might be ipv6 related. Bcause my network uses ipv6 by default, so names translate into ipv6.

Maybe there's a bug? in ubuntu/gnome rdp server? Or some setup or conf that I'm mmissing? Not really sure. But anyway I can connect just fine now.

connection screenshot:
[image]