# "Remote desktop connection low virtual memory" with connection from Win 10 to Ubuntu 22.04 using ipv6 address

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, remote-desktop, ipv6

I have exactly the same question as [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1779079/remote-desktop-connection-low-virtual-memory-after-restart/1779177#1779177). The difference is my client is Windows 10 and my server is Ubuntu 22.04. Because I don't have enough reputations in this community, I can add nothing on that thread.

I notice the same phenomenon as the OP that when I use ipv4 to connect to the server, it works perfectly, but when I use ipv6, boo! "This computer might be low on virtual memory..."

Some community members suggest checking the error in the event viewer. But I don't know where to look at. I have looked at these places, `Applications and Services Logs -> Windows -> TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager` and `Applications and Services Logs -> Windows -> TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager`, no error message. So where should I look at?

update: I have also checked `'Application and Services Logs' > 'Microsoft' > 'Windows' > 'TerminalServices-ClientActiveXCore' > 'Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RDPClient/Operation'` . There is still no the fatal error, except a warning about the TLS encryption. But this warning happens with no matter ipv4 or ipv6.

Comment: Unless you have an answer, submitting a comment, wouldn’t have been appropriate. Why can’t you use an IPv4 address?

Comment: Because the IPv4 address is for intranet. My public address is only available in IPv6.

Comment: @cyfwx - if you use a different RDP client do you get the same behavior?

Comment: @Ramhound Well, I have tried both the Microsoft's official "Remote Desktop" from Play Store on my Android phone and Win 10's official "Remote Desktop Connection". Yes, they are both official ones. In fact, I have met my connection need by ticking "Legacy VNC support" in the Ubuntu's remote desktop settings and connect to it with a VNC client. But I'm still curious about the RDP problem. Do you have any recommendation of 3rd party RDP apps for me to test?

Comment: Software recommendations are strictly not allowed.